# How to list all computers in a windows wi-fi network?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

A wi-fi router has been setup with a number of windows machines connecting to it. How do I use windows command line to list all the computers (either by hostname or ipaddress) in the wi-fi network. OSs on the network are XP, Vista and 7.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have used following procedure:

1. Open Run (<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type `cmd` and click OK.
3. Ping the server if you know or your gateway. Even if there is requested timed out.
4. Type the command `arp -a` .
5. It will usually list down all the IP's and Computers with their Mac Addresses.

If you want to use a GUI tool. I recommend [IPScan](http://www.eusing.com/ipscan/free_ip_scanner.htm). Although it is a light application (433KB), it is freeware that's always worked for me.

You can also use another GUI Tool, [Advance IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/).

Comment: I don't get it. `Pt. #3` says ping server (in my case it's the wi-fi router ip). Did that. `Pt. #4` says type "arp -a". Did that, but I get an error that arp is not a recognized command.

Comment: Did you type without the quotes? Do it without the quotes

Comment: yup .. no quotes.... to confirm again .... I simply type "arp -a" (without quotes) .. into windows command line?

Comment: Well works fine for me it actually the Address Routing Protocol command, why not use IPscan GUI ?

Comment: Well I think you are also using some WIFI encryption key on you network too. That usually prevents the command to execute

Comment: ran arp -a in PowerShell. It worked. Ran windows command line as administrator and then arp -a. It worked. I was testing on a Windows Vista machine with UAC turned on; so running cmd as administrator was needed. Thanks for the great command.

Comment: Well yea that is also one issue, I have been using CMD with Admin powers! So yea! No Problem

Comment: How do we ping the server with CMD?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Answer (score 12):

`net view` will probably show most of them.

Comment: ... does `net view` require any folders to be shared on the other PCs in the network? ... I tried it and it lists only my PC as `\\<PC NAME>`

Comment: But it will only list the names, not the IP and Mac addresses but it works. Good answer

Comment: Is there any alternative to net view command, I got below error --

C:\Users\vipin>net view
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.